# How group by sum and average column in python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, aggregate

As input I have a CSV file with times and a bunch of numbers for each time.

```
Time,F1,F2,F3
8:11,5,2,4
9:25,9,8,2
9:39,7,3,2
9:53,6,5,1
10:07,4,6,7
10:21,7,3,1
10:35,5,6,7
11:49,1,2,1
12:03,3,3,1
```

I'd like to output the table for each hour grouped by column Avg and Sum:

```
Time,SUM F1,SUM F2,SUM F3,AVG F1,AVG F2,AVG F3
8:00,5,2,4,5,2,4
9:00,22,16,5,7.3,5.3,1.6
10:00,16,15,15,5.3,5,5
11:00,1,2,1,1,2,1
12:00,3,3,1,3,3,1
```

So far I was looking at doing it with a dictionary where hour is a key and value is a list of count and sum, then dividing sum by count to get average.
I'm sure there must be cleaner way to do it. Maybe some library can work with this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your approach is fine. It's not that much code either. A loop to add things to three dictionary, each using setdefault(hour, []).append(F1) and setdefault(hour, []).append(F2) and setdefault(hour, []).append(F3). Then for each dict you iterate through each hour and call 'sum' over the list and divide by count(list) while taking  care to handle what happens when your list is empty.

Comment: `Pandas` is a good library for this kind of data processing : http://pandas.pydata.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('f123.csv')
df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[0] + ':00')
by_hour = df.groupby('Time')
data = {}
for name in ['F1', 'F2', 'F3']:
    data['SUM ' + name] = by_hour[name].sum()
    data['AVG ' + name] = by_hour[name].mean()
res = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(res)
```

prints:

```
         AVG F1    AVG F2    AVG F3  SUM F1  SUM F2  SUM F3
Time                                                       
10:00  5.333333  5.000000  5.000000      16      15      15
11:00  1.000000  2.000000  1.000000       1       2       1
12:00  3.000000  3.000000  1.000000       3       3       1
8:00   5.000000  2.000000  4.000000       5       2       4
9:00   7.333333  5.333333  1.666667      22      16       5
```

Save as csv file:

```
res.to_csv('res.csv')
```

This is the content of `res.csv`:

```
Time,AVG F1,AVG F2,AVG F3,SUM F1,SUM F2,SUM F3
10:00,5.333333333333333,5.0,5.0,16,15,15
11:00,1.0,2.0,1.0,1,2,1
12:00,3.0,3.0,1.0,3,3,1
8:00,5.0,2.0,4.0,5,2,4
9:00,7.333333333333333,5.333333333333333,1.6666666666666667,22,16,5
```

Comment: Great solution! How would you handle new days, given column with Dates next to Time in '22-01-16' format?

Comment: Great that it helped. Pandas is very good reading and working with dates in general. However, answering a new question in a comment is really cumbersome. It would be easier to ask a new question and link it in a comment from here. I will have a look at it.

Comment: Pands looks great indeed, but manipulating data there is not very intuitive at first sight, maybe I should attend one of the python-academy classes. 
Here I've added new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944183/how-to-groupby-two-fields-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you started, it uses Python's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to process the files and [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the entries by hour:

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby, chain

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    header = next(csv_input)
    csv_output.writerow(["Time","SUM F1","SUM F2","SUM F3","AVG F1","AVG F2","AVG F3"])

    for k, g in groupby(csv_input, lambda x: int(x[0].split(':')[0])):
        entries = [(int(f1), int(f2), int(f3)) for t, f1, f2, f3 in g]
        sums = [(sum(x), sum(x)/float(len(entries))) for x in zip(*entries)]
        row = ['{}:00'.format(k)] + list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*sums)))
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

This would give you an output csv file looking like this:

```
 Time,SUM F1,SUM F2,SUM F3,AVG F1,AVG F2,AVG F3
 8:00,5,2,4,5.0,2.0,4.0
 9:00,22,16,5,7.333333333333333,5.333333333333333,1.6666666666666667
 10:00,16,15,15,5.333333333333333,5.0,5.0
 11:00,1,2,1,1.0,2.0,1.0
 12:00,3,3,1,3.0,3.0,1.0
```

`zip` is used to transpose the column entries.

Tested using Python 2.7.9